# LocalStorage is null on staging server. IIS7

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

While leaving page idle for a long duration say 10-15 min., localstorage on the page shows 'null'.

My code is that

`LocalStorageFunc` function is calling on document ready.

```
function LocalStorageFunc(MenuTitle, LinkName) {
   // alert('MenuTitle--' + MenuTitle + 'LinkName----' + LinkName);
    localStorage.setItem("PageTitle", MenuTitle);
    localStorage.setItem("PageName", LinkName);
}
```

I had not found any particular reason that why localStorage value is getting null for page name and page title. while I had never open page with multiple tab and also session does not expire for logged in user. 
`Browser: chrome latest version`.

[image]

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem("PageTitle") != null || localStorage.getItem("PageName") != "") {
            $("#pageTitle").text(localStorage.getItem("PageTitle"));
            $("#PageName").text(localStorage.getItem("PageName"));
        }
    });

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDalx.png


/*---------------------Menu Creation----------------------*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = {
        "MenuLinks": [
            {
                "Title": "Configuration",
                "Fav": 0,
                "Pages": [
                    { "Name": "Define Manufacturer Inventory", "Link": "/Pages/InstallationAndCommissioning/MeterInventory/MeterMaster.aspx" },
                    { "Name": "Entity Configuration", "Link": "/EntityConfiguration/Index" },
                    { "Name": "Substation Configuration", "Link": "/SubStationConfiguration/Index" },
                    { "Name": "Firmware Upgradation", "Link": "/FirmwareUpgradation/Index" },
                    { "Name": "Define Meter Model", "Link": "/Pages/InstallationAndCommissioning/ModbusMeterModal/MODBUSMeterModalLibrary.aspx" }
                ]


            },
            {
                "Title": "Revenue Management",
                "Fav": 0,
                "Pages": [
                    { "Name": "Add Tariff", "Link": "/AddTariff/Index" },
                    { "Name": "Define Tariff", "Link": "/DefineTariff/Index" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Title": "User Management",
                "Fav": 0,
                "Pages": [
                    { "Name": "Define User", "Link": "/Pages/UserManagement/DefineUsers.aspx" },
                    { "Name": "Change Password", "Link": "/Pages/UserManagement/ChangePassword.aspx" },
                    { "Name": "Manage Business Role", "Link": "/Pages/UserManagement/AddEditBusinessRoles.aspx" },
                    { "Name": "Assign Business Role to User", "Link": "/Pages/UserManagement/SearchUserForAssignBusinessRole.aspx" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Title": "Virtual Group",
                "Fav": 0,
                "Pages": [
                    { "Name": "Create Virtual Group", "Link": "/VirtualGroupManagement/AddRule" }
                ]

            }
        ]
    };
    var exp;
    var tempI = 0;
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < data.MenuLinks.length; i++) {

        if (i % 2 == 0) {

            exp = $(
                "<div class='item' id='" +
                +i + "a"
                + "'>");
            exp.appendTo("#carouselwrapper");
            tempI = i;
        }

        var j = 0;
        for (; j < data.MenuLinks[i].Pages.length; j++) {
            var MenuTitle, SubMenuName, SubMenuLink;
            MenuTitle = data.MenuLinks[i].Title;

            SubMenuName = data.MenuLinks[i].Pages[j].Name;
            SubMenuLink = data.MenuLinks[i].Pages[j].Link;

            if (j == 0) {
                exp = $("<div class='MenuTitle' >"
                    + MenuTitle
                    + "</div>");
                exp.appendTo("#" + tempI + "a");
            }

            AppPath = $('#hdnAppPath').val();

            var xPath = "http://" + AppPath + SubMenuLink;;

            exp = $("<div class='MenuItemDiv'>\
                          <a class='MenuItemLink' href='" + xPath + "' target='_self' onClick='OpenLinkPage("
                + '"' + MenuTitle + '",'
                + '"' + SubMenuName + '",'
                + '"' + SubMenuLink + '"'
                + ");' class='pageLink' id='"
                + SubMenuName
                + "'>"
                + SubMenuName
                + "</a></div>");
            exp.appendTo("#" + tempI + "a");

        }
    }
});
/*---------------------Open Page Link----------------------*/
function OpenLinkPage(MenuTitle, LinkName, LinkHref) {

    var path11;

    path11 = 'http://' + AppPath + LinkHref;


    LocalStorageFunc(MenuTitle, LinkName);
    SaveFavRecentLinkInDB(MenuTitle, LinkName, path11, 'R');

    var path11;
    path11 = 'http://' + AppPath + LinkHref;
    // window.open(path11, "_self");
    addRecentLink(MenuTitle, LinkName, LinkHref);
    window.location.href = path11;
    event.preventDefault();

}
```

Created menu item on page load and click on menu to update local storage value

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: When are those last two lines called?

Comment: updated code please check

Comment: Where you are calling LocalStorageFunc function. Its not showing in your code as document.ready function.

Comment: did u check the in chrome resouces ?

Comment: I have updated code, i'm creating menu on page load from json object and when I click on menu Item I have call LocalstorageFun to update page name and title according to menu clicking.